# How to obtain diamonds representing the effect sizes including the confidence intervals in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have written out a code for a forest plot. As you can see in the plot, I have confidence intervals drawn along with sqaures.

Instead of these squares with CIs on either side, I would like to obtain diamonds that engulf the CIs (as this plot is summary plot).

Basically, would want to see big diamonds for big squares and longer CIs and vice versa.

```
   #My APA-format theme


apatheme=theme_bw()+ 
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_blank(),
        axis.line=element_line(),
        text=element_text(family='Times'),
        legend.position='bottom', axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"))

credplot.gg <- function(d){
  # d is a data frame with 4 columns
  # d$x gives variable names
  # d$y gives center point
  # d$ylo gives lower limits
  # d$yhi gives upper limits
  require(ggplot2)
  p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, ymin=ylo, ymax=yhi))+ylim(c(-1,6))+geom_pointrange()+geom_point(aes(size=y), shape=15)+
    coord_flip() + apatheme+ geom_hline(aes(x=0,yintercept=0), lty=2)+ xlab('Studies')+ ylab('Standardized Mean Difference')+ggtitle("Comparison of treatment approaches")
  return(p)}

# load your data below 
d <- read.delim("Summary_1.txt", head=T)
Summary_1 <-credplot.gg(d) +xlim( "Simple-to-Untreated-Complex (n=4)",
                                 "Simple-to-Simple (n=11)",
                                 "Complex-to-Untreated-Simple (n=5)",
                                 "Complex-to-Complex (n=13)")



                                       x    y   ylo yhi
1   Complex-to-Complex (n=13)   0.984274064 1.061273278 0.907274851
2   Complex-to-Untreated-Simple (n=5)   2.687432561 3.53724909  1.837616031
3   Simple-to-Simple (n=11) 1.671591517 2.179163075 1.164019959
4   Simple-to-Untreated-Complex (n=4)   0.236442055 0.32407191  0.148812199
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of such diamonds? It's not clear to me what you're after. You'll probably have to calculate the coordinates yourself and use either `geom_path` or `geom_polygon` to make the diamonds.

Comment: @Axeman: Here is an example of such a diamond plotted in forest plots usually to summarize findings from a bunch of studies: [link] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest_plot#/media/File:Generic_forest_plot.png)  Basically, what I am trying to do is to construct diamond (which is infact a square rotated by 45 degrees) in place of existing usual squares such that confidence intervals form the diagonal of the diamond. So, for doing this, **I may require a R command that plots area (0.5dsquare)** but I do not know which one, I tried scale_size_area() but I guess it isn't the right direction.